# Is it possible that Moshe visited Cana'an between leaving Egypt and the burning bush?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash, canaan

We can say it was all prophecy, but in *parshat Re'ay* Moshe knows about all the *bamot* across the Jordan and is super concerned that *bnei yisrael* will sacrifice in other places than *hamakome* that God will choose. There are about 40 years, undocumented in the Torah, when he's living as Yitro's son in law, until the burning bush: is it such a reach to say Moshe had visited there?

Comment: [Deuteronomy 34:1](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0534.htm)

Comment: isnt that at the end of his life, and he only gets an eagle eye view?